# Printf on masm x64 with multiple parameters

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, masm

I need to create a function in asm (on Windows) that replicates the following behaviour:

```
_int64 q(_int64 a, _int64 b, _int64 c, _int64 d, _int64 e) {
     _int64 sum = a + b + c + d + e;
      printf("a = %I64d b = %I64d c = %I64d d = %I64d e = %I64d sum = %I64d\n", a, b, c, d, e, sum);
      return sum;
}
```

I know I need to allocate shadow space for printf and also that I need to store some parameters in the stack, because only the first 4 parameters are in registers (rcx, rdx, r8 and r9)

My problem comes with the string format and the stack management.
My code so far looks like this:

```
.data   
string1 dq 'a = %I64d b = %I64d c = %I64d d = %I64d e = %I64d sum = %I64d', 10, 0       ; The printf format, "\n",'0'

.code
    public      q                               ;a in rcx, b in rdx, c in r8, d in r9, e in stack
    q:          push rbp
                mov rbp, rsp                    
                sub rsp, 32                     ;allocating shadow space for printf
                                                ;for calling printf, we need to have [string] in rcx, 
                                                ;a in rdx, b in r8, c in r9, d in stack1, e in stack2, and sum in stack3
                add rax, rcx                    ;first make the sum
                add rax, rdx                    
                add rax, r8
                add rax, r9
                mov rbx, [rbp + 8]              ;getting e from the stack
                add rax, rbx                    ;final add, in rax now is sum
                push rax                        ;changing parameters in registers (last 3 in stack)
                push rbx
                push r9
                mov r9, r8                      ;c in r9
                mov r8, rdx                     ;b in r8
                mov rdx, rcx                    ;a in rdx
                lea rcx, [string]               ;string in rcx
                call printf
                mov rsp, rbp                    ;back to previous pointer
                pop rbp                         ;release resources
                ret 0
    end
```

At this moment it does not compile, with an

> error A2084: constant value too large

I don't know if I need to change the format or split it in 2, in that case I need to storage some other parameter in the stack, and then I am not very sure how to proceed...

Comment: Which line is the error on?  On the string?  Use `db`, you don't want the `10, 0` elements padded to qwords even if it did accept this the way NASM does.

Comment: Also, you need to `sub rsp, 32`to reserve shadow space *after* pushing 3 registers, if you want to restore them after.  Otherwise those 24 bytes are the bottom of the shadow space the called function (`printf`) sees.  But that's pointless because you're not restoring them after the call.  So you violate the calling convention by clobbering `rbx`; use a different reg. Also, you'll need `call _printf` because that's how Windows decorates C names.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes in the string declaration... with that i have the following  error A2006: undefined symbol : string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that error is on the line with the string, use `db` instead of `dq`: you don't want the `10, 0` elements padded to qwords even if it did accept the quoted part as a string the way NASM does.

I think MASM allows quoted constants for `db`, so that should get it to assemble.

---

And then we have multiple other bugs at runtime:

Also, you need to `sub rsp, 32`to reserve shadow space *after* pushing 3 registers, if you want to restore them after.  Otherwise those 24 bytes are the bottom of the shadow space the called function (`printf`) sees.

But that's pointless because you're not restoring them after the call.  So you violate the calling convention by clobbering `rbx`; It doesn't look like you're doing anything with them after the call, so just use a call-clobbered reg, or better calculate the value in the right arg-passing register in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, now it works but e and sum are not working fine. I don't really understand the last paragraph, though :S. Don't I still need to allocate shadow space for printf to use it??

Comment: @MartaLobo: Yes, any function you call is allowed to stomp all over 32 bytes above the return address.  You need to make sure those bytes aren't holding anything valuable.  Now that it assembles, use a debugger to find out what your code is doing when you single step.  But I notice you start with `add rax, rcx` instead of `mov`, and RAX initially holds whatever garbage your caller left there.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, and I added a couple xor to reset the registers. Now the only problem I have left is how to get 'e' from the stack and add it propperly...

Comment: @MartaLobo: have you tried just looking at optimized compiler output for the C function?  Put your function on https://godbolt.org/ and compile it with x86-64 MSVC `-Ox`.  Don't forget about the shadow space your own caller leaves above the return address before the stack args.

Comment: Thank you very much, that website is very very useful!